# Simplecrypt lets my QT application crash on OS X Mountain Lion but works perfect on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, cross-platform, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using [Simplecrypt](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Simple_encryption) to encrypt and decrypt some basic stuff in my QT application (c++).
On Windows 7 everything compiles fine and works like expected.
On Mac OS X Mountain Lion, the app crashes with the following error during launch:

```
ASSERT: "i >= 0 && i < size()" in file 
./../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h, line 414
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

It does compile, but the precompiler gives me some errors about OS X Mountain Lion. I have no idea if this has something to do with it:

```
../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:328:6: warning: #warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
```

Is it possible to get Simplecrypt to work on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: That warning seems pretty easy to understand to me. Seems like that program is not yet suited for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ASSERT, it seems to be an out of array exception not catch when using a QByteArray.

What is the line of YOUR code that is causing the crash? Have you try to debug to see what happens?

The warning during precompilation only indicates that Qt 4.8 does not support MacOS X Mountain Lion so some bugs and unwanted behavior can happen.

Comment: The code that I'm using is the following: SimpleCrypt crypto(Q_UINT64_C(0x0ca94c63e6ee6d)); and also: crypto.decryptToString(loadSettings("pwd","").

Comment: This is odd, when I compile it again everything works :D. I will report back when it happens again, because I haven't changed anything in the code...

Comment: Was is the return type of `loadSettings` ? QByteArray or QString ? If it's QByteArray maybe error is in this function. You should debug your program to check what happens.

Comment: The return type of loadSettings is a QString. I will do some debugging when I found out how to do that :).